# Micro-switch inductive switching (DC)

Tags: inductive, switching

I need to check if a micro-switch can do the below (Honeywell 11SM1-H2):

"the contacts shall switch an inductive load below 53V DC / 0.4A with a time constant of 40ms"

I'm not sure I understand what is being asked.  My understanding is this: the load has a time constant of 40ms, meaning that L/R = 0.04.  R = 133 Ohms (using I and V), giving an inductance of 6H, which is massive.

If the switch was abrubtly opened, the back EMF will be extremely large and it won't be possible to fit a freewheeling diode across the coil.

I've asked the manufacturer if this can be done and they said they could run tests, but couldn't at the moment due to heavy workloads.

I'm not sure if I'm looking at this properly.  The only other thing it could mean (that I can think of) is that the 40ms time constant doesn't refer to the load, but to the switch response time.  This would depend on the inductance though.

Are they saying 'this is the load, can you do it?' or are they saying 'here is the load, can you switch it within this time?'?

Comment: Sounds like the settling time to me.

Comment: Beware that microswitches are often rated for AC volts, and when used on DC, they can switch only a much lower voltage. They also fail much sooner on DC (from first-hand personal experience with a 36V DC electric vehicle).

Comment: I'm not sure what they're asking (specs written by non-techies are often that way), but I think you're mistaken on the back EMF part.  It's theoretically infinite regardless of inductance.  The operating rule for inductors is that they resist changes in current.  Therefore, any diode that can handle the operating current for the time needed to dissipate the energy in the inductor would be adequate.  Keep in mind though, that by allowing current to flow after the switch is off, you're effectively extending the ON time, which may or may not be acceptable.  A/The resistor might help with that.

Comment: @JohnHonniball this switch is actually only rated at 30VDC.  I understand that DC switch ratings are always lower.  Honeywell didn't reject it out-of-hand though.

Comment: ...if indeed there even is an inductor.  They might have a mistaken idea that mechanical switches have an analog charge/discharge curve similar to an RC circuit.  Actually, they "bounce", making many ON/OFF transitions before finally settling in the correct state.  They could be referring to the maximum settling time.

Comment: @AaronD, I was thinking along those lines - that the protection circuitry will add to the response time and this is what they are asking - can you switch it in this time?

Comment: @AaronD, surely 'time constant' doesn't make sense in that context.

Comment: @user57709  Technically no, but you can't assume that when dealing with non-techies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is "time constant" when we are talking about switches?**

Picture below should explain everything. Some manufacturers, for some products provide tables like this:

[image]

Source: https://www.yaskawa.com/pycprd/attachments/Switch/kae542-0.pdf

---

**Can Honeywell 11SM1-H2 switch 53V/0.4A RL circuit with time constant 40ms?**

**Short answer:**

Yes, it should be able switch that, but it will wear out faster (or maybe very fast). If I'm not mistaken - datasheet says that switch is rated at 30V and 5A. Your voltage requrement is much higher, but current is pretty low, so I think it should work. You can buy 3-5 switches and do some experiments on your own, switch them 1000 times or more with "40ms inductive load" with required current and voltage, disassemble it and see if contacts are damaged or not after 1000 or more operations.

**Long answer:**

When we are talking about switching inductive load - there are few important parameters:

- voltage
- current
- time constant of circuit

All these parameters affect electric arc properties. Electric arc damages contacts (high temperature and chemical/ionic reactions). If voltage and current are high - arc power can be high.

**If time constant is long - arc may burn for longer time.** Longer time means more energy. More energy will heat up contacts to higher temperature. Specyfic heat of metals is very low (compared to water for example), it is very easy to heat up tiny metal concact to very high temperature.

When you are switching AC currents - arc typically goes out after current reaches zero so energy is much lower (compared to switching DC coils, motors etc.).

So... maybe yes, maybe not. It depends how often switch will be used.

**Suggestion:**

In my opinion - if you want to switch 53V 0.4A inductive load that has 40ms time constant with this tiny switch - I think you should:

- add something that will "eat energy" from discharging coil, maybe some capacitor or flyback diode or
- use some relay driven from that tiny switch
- use diffrent switch, one with known switching capabilities (at your desired current, voltage, and your circit time constant)

Comment: I updated "short answer" part.

Answer (score 0):

The time constant is indeed L/R, where L is the inductance and R the resistance of the circuit. This value is important because it sets a limit on how long it will take for the arc to extinguish when the switch contacts open.

So why not simply specify a maximum inductance? Many loads such as relays, solenoids, and motors have an inductance which varies depending on what they are doing, and few have the value stated in their specs. Measuring in-circuit inductance directly is often difficult, but it can be roughly estimated from the length of time it takes for the current to decay. And since that is what we want to know anyway...

An inductance of several henries might seem unrealistic, but is not unusual for a large electromagnetic device. For example the [Panasonic S4EB-48V](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e_download/control/relay/power/catalog/mech_eng_s.pdf) has a coil inductance of 3.41H - and that is just a small relay.

If you are worried about arcing contacts due to a highly inductive load, simply put a diode across it in reverse. When the switch opens the diode will immediately become forward biased by the back-emf and maintain current flow until it decays, without allowing a dangerous voltage to build up.